# Fail to install QGIS on my mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, qgis

I tried several times to install almost everything from the website, http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

However, when I open QGIS, the initial image just got stuck on the sentence "starting python" and then just quit automatically.

My mac OS version is 10.8.5
Is such a problem due to my two versions of python in my system? The python in my system is 2.7.5, and perviously I also installed a standard version of python which is about 3.3. Then I realize that I could just use the 2.7 one instead, so I just dragged the whole fold named "python" from my application folder into trashcan and use the 2.7 from terminal instead. But I'm afraid that doesn't work either...

And how can I install the QGIS correctly now? the process seems to messy to me as a beginner...